Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment'
I have a Blazor server-side app upgraded to the latest version of NET8. When starting the app I am getting the following exception:

Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment' for service type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment'.

When calling:
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            var builder = config.Build();
            var env = context.HostingEnvironment;

            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        })
        .UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
            .ReadFrom.Services(services)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext())
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });

And the stack trace:

at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.Populate() in //src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/src/ServiceLookup/CallSiteFactory.cs:line 78
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options) in //src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/src/ServiceProvider.cs:line 63
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options) in //src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/src/ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.cs:line 57
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.InitializeServiceProvider() in //src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/HostBuilder.cs:line 359
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build() in /_/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/HostBuilder.cs:line 164
at MyApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\MyApp\MyApp\Program.cs:line 31

What am I missing?

Blazor is web application and to correctly build such web application, you need to use WebApplicationBuilder from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder namespace.
Like below:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

This initializes new WebApplicationBuilder, which is then able to build and run web app.
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder method, as can be read in docs:

Initializes a new instance of the HostBuilder class with pre-configured defaults.

